# Selecting a div unselects the other divs like a radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a list of divs using a loop from the database..
[image]

when i  click select..it becomes like
[image]

the problem i am facing is that at a time i can select only one company...how could i select a nother company that will make the previous selected company unselect...
the program is like this...

```
{section name=i loop=$id7}
  <div class="company" style="width:220px; height:220px; background-color:white;margin-left:12px;margin-bottom:22px;float:left;" >

    <div id="ctable">
      <table style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:18px;width:178px;height:149px;">
        <tr style="text-align:center;">
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="center" height="42px">{$id7[i].vCompanyName}</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="center" height="107px">
            <img src="{$tconfig.tsite_images}{$id7[i].vImage}">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>  


    <div id="selecty" class="{$id7[i].iEmployerId}" style="width:178px;height:32px; margin-left:18px;">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selecty_hide('{$id7[i].iEmployerId}','{$smarty.section.i.index}')" class="but_blue_small">Select</a>
    </div>

    <div id="selected_state" style="width:198px;height:32px;display:none;background-color:white;margin-left:16px;">&nbsp;
      <img src="{$tconfig.tsite_images}tick.png" />&nbsp;<font color="#cdcdcd"><b>Company selected</b></font>
    </div>   
  </div>
{/section}
```

and its javascript is like this

```
<script>
  function selecty_hide (eid,compid) {
    alert(eid);
    alert(compid);
    document.getElementById('selecty').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('selected_state').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('eid').value=eid;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what if somebody selects a company accidentally ?? there is no option for unselect that.

Comment: there is a next button on top of page....when somebody selects one company then he select the next button for further navigation

Comment: @RenMathew i have did a Fiddle with your question solved, look my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look, its simple, you can just solve your problem this way: Adding and removing CSS Classes.

**I have made a full [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AMe73/1/) to you know what i'm talking about.**

**Modified the HTML Company Div to be only one and not two divs:**

```html
<div id="selecty" class="selectable_state" onclick=select_unselect('{$id7[i].iEmployerId}','{$smarty.section.i.index}') >
    Select
</div>
```

**And modified the js:**

```js
function select_unselect(eid,compid){
    alert(eid);
    alert(compid);
    if ($(this).hasClass('selectable_state'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selectable_state');
        $(this).addClass('selected_state');
        $(this).html('Company Selected');
        $('#eid').val(eid);
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('selected_state');
        $(this).addClass('selectable_state');
        $(this).html('Select');
        $('#eid').val('');        
    }
  }
```

**Ps: please note that in the fiddle i removed some parameters of the function to make it work because i do not have all the data to make it work properly.**

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery it is easy

```
<div class="mydiv" style="cursor: pointer;">
    box 1
</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="cursor: pointer;">
    box 2
</div>
<div class="mydiv" style="cursor: pointer;">
    box 3
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".mydiv").click(function() { 
        if($(this).hasClass("selected") == false) {
            $(".mydiv").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(".mydiv").removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This will remove the class "selected" from all elements with class "mydiv" and then add it to the single element you have clicked.

It also supports unselecting the current element + you can drop your buttons completely it is enough to click on the div!

You should be able to adjust my example to your code.

All you need to do now is define a custom class for the div that will display its content different like only show "company selected" when the div has the class "selected".

Have fun and good luck!

Comment: You need to invert your if statement for it to work as intended :)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a class(selected_company) for selected company div.
When someone choose any other div then get previous selected div and remove this class then add this class in current selected div.

Something like this:

```
$(".selected_company").removeClass('selected_company');
$(this).addClass('selected_company');
```

Then at a time only one company will be selected.

Here is an example demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kRD4S/

Answer (score 1):

Well little modification in javscript can be done as below

```
<script>
function selecty_hide (eid,compid,element) {
   alert(eid);
   alert(compid);
   document.getElementById('selecty').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('ctable').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('selected_state').style.display="none";
   element.style.display="block";
   document.getElementById('eid').value=eid;
 }
```

need to pass another parameter during function call(3rd param) as 'this'

```
 onclick="selecty_hide('{$id7[i].iEmployerId}','{$smarty.section.i.index}',this)"
```

The script above will first display none all the div with id selecty,ctable,selected_state and this will display block the selected div.

Hope this Help you

Answer (score 0):

Think of it slightly different. If Company A is selected, and the user now selects Company B:

- Unselect ALL elements.
- Now select Company B

If you do it like this, there's no hassle in trying to figure out which company you need to unselect.

Something like this:

```
$(".company").click(function() {
    //remember the new item
    var clickedItem = $(this);

    //unselect everything
    $(".company").removeClass("companySelected");

    //select the company that was clicked
    clickedItem.addClass("companySelected");
});
```